# Self-invoking class instantiation with es6 classes

Tags: javascript, function, class

I am trying to use [Simple “Class” Instantiation](https://johnresig.com/blog/simple-class-instantiation/) where a class can return a `new` version of itself and return an instantiated version of itself.

```
function User(first, last){
  if ( this instanceof User ) {
    this.name = first + " " + last;
  } else
    return new User(first, last);
}
```

I'm trying to see if this is possible with es6 classes.

```
class User {
  constructor(first, last){
    if ( this instanceof User ) {
      this.name = first + " " + last;
    } else
      return new User(first, last);
    }
  }  
}
```

However I'm running into this error:

> TypeError: Class constructor User cannot be invoked without
>   'new'

I'm wondering if there's a way around it.

Comment: It's a constructor, not a function. Therefore you cannot use the instanceof trick. The work around is to use a constructor function instead of a class like you previously did. They're more flexible.

Comment: "They're more flexible."...and more JavaScript like ;-)

Comment: The module system(s) make(s) this easy:  let instance = new User(); export instance; // will always produce a Singleton.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering if there's a way around it.

Well, no. And I think that is a good thing. The advantage of using ES6 Class over the previous method is that it actually behaves like a class, without the quirks and confusion. If you take the reasons to do what you are trying to do, from the article you referenced:

> First is an issue that new JavaScript programmers will encounter. On a
>   quick observation of the above code it isn’t immediately obvious that
>   the function is actually something that is meant to be instantiated...
>
> Secondly, if a Class-style function is meant to be instantiated, and
>   isn’t, it can in turn end up polluting the current scope...

And those are some of the issues ES6 aims to resolve. So, now, new programmer comes in, try to invoke a class the wrong way, and boom: TypeError. No polluted scope, no unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have made an error on line #5:

```
class User {
  constructor(first, last){
    if ( this instanceof User ) {
      this.name = first + " " + last;
    } else // bad line
      return new User(first, last);
    }
  }  
}
```